# how to initialize the members of a dynamicly allocated structure

Tags: c, dynamic, structure

I have allocated memory for two structures and I am trying to give some values to the members of the structures.However, it is not working and I do not know what to do. Please help me understand what is happening. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <std lib.h>
struct rec{
    int i;
    double f;
    char c;
};

int main(){

    struct rec *p;
    p = (struct rec *) malloc(2*sizeof(struct rec));

    p[0]->i = 10;
    p[0]->f = 3.1;
    p[0]->c = 'a';

    p[1]->i = 20;
    p[1]->f = 6.2;
    p[1]->c = 'b';

    free(p);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Use `.` instead of `->`. the `[]` is already doing the dereferencing.

Comment: Either do `p[1].c = ...`  or `(p + 1)->c = ...` with the former being the preferred notation.

Comment: As a rule you should always say what it _does_ do, and how that is different from what you want it to do.

Comment: BTW, "*it is not working*" is the more or less worth trouble description one can give.

Comment: BTW^2: Do not cast  malloc() & friends in C.

Comment: Turn WARNINGS of your compiler on. It should have warned you!.

Comment: now I understand how things work

Answer (score 1):

For example `p[0]` already dereferences your `struct rec *p`, that is why when you try to compile your code you will recieve the following error:

`error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct rec’)`

and gcc will also tell you where this error occured, e.g.:

`p[0]->c = 'a';`  (source code line 14)

That happens since you tried to dereference your already dereferenced `p[0]`.

Now to fix this just switch out the `->` for a `.` or alternatively you could also use `(p + x)->` (`x` being a valid number, in your case from 0 to 1) to dereference your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct rec{
    int i;
    double f;
    char c;
};

int main(){
    struct rec *p;
    p = (struct rec *) malloc(2 * sizeof(struct rec));


    (p + 0)->i = 10;
    (p + 0)->f = 3.1;
    (p + 0)->c = 'a';

    (p + 1)->i = 20;
    (p + 1)->f = 6.2;
    (p + 1)->c = 'b';

    printf("%d\t%f\t%c\n", (p + 0)->i, (p + 0)->f, (p + 0)->c);
    printf("%d\t%f\t%c\n", (p + 1)->i, (p + 1)->f, (p + 1)->c);
    free(p);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember to check the return value of `malloc`, it could be 0.
2. Further, I've rewritten your code such that `p` is a *pointer to an
   array of 2 `struct rec`*, so the usage of the main part of code is
   closer to what you wanted originally.
3. Further, never cast the result of a `malloc`, you could hide nasty
   bugs of mismatching pointer types if you later change the type of
   pointer being declared.
4. Lastly, always try use the `malloc` idiom where you `malloc` the
   sizeof the thing you're pointing at. That way, if you decide to
   change the thing you're `malloc`ing, the correct size is always
   returned.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rec{
    int i;
    double f;
    char c;
};

int main(void){    
    struct rec (*p)[2] = malloc(sizeof *p);

    if(p)
    {
        (*p)[0].i = 10;
        (*p)[0].f = 3.1;
        (*p)[0].c = 'a';

        (*p)[1].i = 20;
        (*p)[1].f = 6.2;
        (*p)[1].c = 'b';

        printf("%d\t%f\t%c\n", (*p)[0].i, (*p)[0].f, (*p)[0].c);
        printf("%d\t%f\t%c\n", (*p)[1].i, (*p)[1].f, (*p)[1].c);

        free(p);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*is closer to what you wanted originally*" mind elaborating a bit on this?

Comment: @alk The original poster used p[0]->i meaning to me he'd like to use the thing he malloc'ed syntactically as if it were an array. So, why not then allocate an actual array and use it as such?

Comment: 3. is rather done to prevent bugs on legacy C90 systems when one forgets to include stdlib.h. "if you later change the type of pointer being declared" doesn't apply since `int* foo = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));` won't compile anyway. Best advise is to avoid ancient C90.

Comment: @Lundin, you're correct, but since I tend to write for many legacy systems, a prefer to use idioms that ALWAYS compile correctly, if possible :)

Comment: @alk, thanks just speed typing and missed it. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Gunther Schulz: Hi, thank you your help. I would like to ask you something. What should I do if I want to allocate memory dynamically for the array of structures?

Comment: @BogdanZafiescu, the dynamic allocation is on the first line of main above. I'm not sure what you're asking in the comment?

Comment: @BogdanZafiescu, If you are asking about changing the size of the allocated array on-the-fly, look in to using realloc - but beware of its correct use - see http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Realloc